# How to remove duplication in a multi-dimensional array like this(PHP)

Tags: php

I try to combine result from several queries and put them into an array. I found there are some duplications exist. What I want to do is keep the first record and remove the following same records if duplication exist. I want to write a function to filter array and remove duplications. Can anyone help me with it? thanks

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(14) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(7) "2620613"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(5) "Susan"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(9) "Alexander"
    ["client"]=>
    string(7) "Pro"
    ["ssn"]=>
    string(9) "4234324"
    ["hiredate"]=>
    string(10) "2008-04-11"
    ["hra_id"]=>
    string(6) "43244"
    ["hra_date"]=>
    string(10) "2011-08-17"
    ["hra_maileddate"]=>
    NULL
    ["screening_id"]=>
    string(6) "3764551"
    ["screening_date"]=>
    string(10) "2011-08-12"
    ["screening_maileddate"]=>
    NULL
    ["ref"]=>
    string(1) "D"
    ["mailable"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(14) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(7) "263453"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(6) "Dharti"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(6) "Surani"
    ["client"]=>
    string(7) "Pro"
    ["ssn"]=>
    string(9) "345325"
    ["hiredate"]=>
    string(10) "2002-04-29"
    ["hra_id"]=>
    string(6) "3455345"
    ["hra_date"]=>
    string(10) "2010-03-22"
    ["hra_maileddate"]=>
    NULL
    ["screening_id"]=>
    string(6) "234234"
    ["screening_date"]=>
    string(10) "2011-07-11"
    ["screening_maileddate"]=>
    NULL
    ["ref"]=>
    string(1) "D"
    ["mailable"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(14) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(7) "2685056"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(4) "Alex"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(2) "Hu"
    ["client"]=>
    string(7) "Pro"
    ["ssn"]=>
    string(9) "000005562"
    ["hiredate"]=>
    string(10) "2011-09-15"
    ["hra_id"]=>
    string(6) "528948"
    ["hra_date"]=>
    string(10) "2011-07-06"
    ["hra_maileddate"]=>
    NULL
    ["screening_id"]=>
    string(6) "377382"
    ["screening_date"]=>
    string(10) "2011-06-15"
    ["screening_maileddate"]=>
    NULL
    ["ref"]=>
    string(1) "D"
    ["mailable"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(14) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(7) "2685056"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(4) "Alex"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(2) "Hu"
    ["client"]=>
    string(7) "Pro"
    ["ssn"]=>
    string(9) "000005562"
    ["hiredate"]=>
    string(10) "2011-09-15"
    ["hra_id"]=>
    string(6) "528948"
    ["hra_date"]=>
    string(10) "2011-07-06"
    ["hra_maileddate"]=>
    NULL
    ["screening_id"]=>
    string(6) "377971"
    ["screening_date"]=>
    string(10) "2011-09-13"
    ["screening_maileddate"]=>
    NULL
    ["ref"]=>
    string(1) "E"
    ["mailable"]=>
    string(3) "Yes"
  }
}
```

I try to use the following function to remove duplications, but it doesn't work very well and may cause error on some cases.

```
 $resultDE = array_merge($resultD1, $resultE1, $resultE2);
  function specified_array_unique($array) 
  { 
      for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++){
        if(($array[$i]['user_id'] == $array[$i+1]['user_id']) && isset($array[$i+1]))
         unset($array[$i+1]); 
      }

      return $array; 
  } 

 var_dump(super_unique($resultDE));
```

Comment: If you can give us the code you have so far, we can help you get it working...

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: You'll need to tell us your definition of "duplicate". None of the arrays in your example are exactly the same and, though some of us are fricking amazing at what we do, we are not psychics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide which array key you are going to use to determine whether the record is a duplicate or not. In the following example, you would pass this key into the second parameter.

**EDIT** I just made this MUCH more efficient..

```
function array_remove_duplicates ($array, $key) {
  $temp = array();
  foreach ($array as $k => $record) {
    if (isset($record[$key])) {
      // We're only going to filter records that actually have the supplied key present
      if (in_array($record[$key],$temp)) {
        // Key already exists, ignore this one
        unset($array[$k]);
      } else {
        // Key doesn't exist, add it to the tracking array
        $temp[] = $record[$key];
      }
    }
  }
  // we have filtered out the records we don't want so re-order the indexes and return the array
  return array_merge($array);
}

// ...and you could use it like this
$filteredArray = array_remove_duplicates($originalArray,'user_id');
```

Comment: @user921902: If this is the best answer, please "accept" it by clicking the checkmark next to it under the votes.

Answer (score 0):

Try `array_unique($myarray)` (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)).

Edit:
Never mind, this doesn't work with multi-dimensional arrays. However, it could work if you first convert all the arrays to strings, then convert them back to arrays afterwards.

Comment: Note that array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through your array, checking user id:

```
$userIds = array();

foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
    if (in_array($user['user_id'], $userIds)) {
        unset($users[$key]);
    } else {
        $userIds[] = $user['user_id'];
    }
}
```